# Online activation using mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have an activation system at my application.

When user enter the key it log in to online host Mysql database and check if key exist to activate. This is going really slow 2 min per key. Is there any way for faster check and activation ?

Code :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1).ToString = TextBox1.Text And ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2).ToString = "no" Then
                Dim sqlquery1 = "UPDATE tablename SET used = 'Yes' WHERE id = '" & CInt(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString) & "'"
```

If you need more code just let me know ill copy entire code

Comment: I would be more concerned with the open door to Sql Injection.

Comment: @Steve you mean this ? `mysqlconnection3.ConnectionString = "server=; Port=2083; user id=; password=; database="
            mysqlconnection3.Open()`

Comment: Nope, read about Sql Injection [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) or more formally [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: How many rows are in `ds.Tables(0)`?

Comment: Why not specify the table, instead of going through the entire dataset? ds??  even create a store procedure to load the query and other for the update?